# How do I set up a private Git repository on GitHub? Is it even possible?

Tags: git, github

I intend to share my source code on an invite-only basis to a few dozen users maybe. The source code itself should not be public. Participants are allowed and encouraged to submit their changes. So I need source control, preferably Git, hosted on a public server with private access for multiple users.

I learned that it is possible to set up private Git repositories on GitHub which use https:// links. On GitHub itself such a project does not show up in searches. For participating users the project shows a "lock" icon. So there are obviously private repositories; I just don't know how set one up. A lot of tutorials use SSH to set up private repositories but they all require you to have "your own server".

I don't care about secure connections when pushing/pulling source code nor do I have trust issues with GitHub. All I care about is giving access only to users I invite. Maybe I'm naive and such a solution is only available via commercial hosting (e.g., [Unfuddle](https://unfuddle.com/), [Assembla](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Assembla)), but if not, I'd really like to know how it's done!

Comment: Since January 2019 (8+ years later), **unlimited free private repositories are available on GitHub**. See [my answer below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54080912/6309)

Comment: Since April 2020, GitHub also [offers](https://github.blog/changelog/2020-04-14-private-repositories-with-unlimited-collaborators-available-to-all-github-accounts-and-changes-to-github-paid-plans/)  __unlimited collaborators in free private projects__. For comparison, GitLab limits to 5 users per top level group in private projects (as of June 2023). So does BitBucket.

Answer (score 116, accepted):

On January 7th 2019, GitHub [announced](https://blog.github.com/changelog/2019-01-08-pricing-changes/) free and unlimited private repositories for all GitHub users, paying or not. When creating a new repository, you can simply select the Private option.

Comment: Darn, i'd be ok with 5 private collaborators if i had a larger number of users having private read-only access as well.

Comment: Just to add, if you are an organization the smallest plan is $25 a month and you get 10 repos.

Comment: unlimited private repositories $7 per monnth these are for one repositories(one Project)?

Comment: @MinTheinWin: No, you pay $7 for the account, and within that account you can create unlimited private repositories.

Comment: This is now outdated you can have free private repositories

Comment: You can have now free private repositories 2019

Answer (score 76):

[Bitbucket](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitbucket) - Their plans seem to be the best. They give you way more than GitHub do for free accounts - in fact, I'm still only using the free plan - no need to sign up to the paid ones; plus the interface is almost identical to GitHub.

A repository on Bitbucket can have up to *five* private users with unlimited public or private repositories - the only thing you seem to be paying for with the paid accounts are more users to access your private repositories.

Comment: I'm also using bitbucket. And I have to add, that if you invite others to bitbucket you get a bonus: your private repositories could be shared among (up to) 8 users!

Comment: "plus the interface is almost identical to Github" At one point this may have been the case, but no longer. GitHub's UI is much simpler and more usable in my opinion. Since Bitbucket was mentioned, there's also  [GitLab](https://www.gitlab.com/).

Comment: I agree! As you stated, it was quite similar when I dropped the answer in but now feels clunk and poorly thought about when compared to GitHub. I have since moved everything to GitHub under a paid subscription and not looked back!

Answer (score 60):

If you are a student you can get a free private repository at https://github.com/edu

**Update**

As noted in [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2600240/188264), now there is an option for private repos also for simple users

Comment: As I see now the text on the button says "Request a discount". So, I guess that even being a student you only get a discount, but not a free private repository.

Comment: @jutky no, you get a free micro plan for a limited time (I think 2 years). ["Discounted and **free** plans are available for educational use"](https://education.github.com/discount_requests/new)

Comment: You may want to [update your answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2600230/how-do-i-set-up-a-private-git-repository-on-github-is-it-even-possible/2600240#2600240).

Answer (score 14):

GitHub is a great tool in-all for making repositories. However, it does not do good with private repositories.

You're forced to pay for private repositories unless you get some sort of plan. I have a couple of projects so far, and if GitHub doesn't do what I want I just go to Bitbucket. It's a bit harder to work with than GitHub, however it's unlimited free repositories.

Answer (score 8):

Since January 7th, 2019, it *is* possible: unlimited free private repositories on GitHub!
... But for up to three collaborators per private repository.

[Nat Friedman](https://twitter.com/natfriedman) just [announced it by twitter](https://twitter.com/natfriedman/status/1082345111566970880):

> Today(!) we’re thrilled to announce unlimited free private repos for all GitHub users, and a new simplified Enterprise offering:

"[New year, new GitHub: Announcing unlimited free private repos and unified Enterprise offering](https://blog.github.com/2019-01-07-new-year-new-github/)"

> For the first time, developers can use GitHub for their private projects with up to three collaborators per repository for free.
>
> Many developers want to use private repos to apply for a job, work on a side project, or try something out in private before releasing it publicly.
>   Starting today, those scenarios, and many more, are possible on GitHub at no cost.
>
> Public repositories are still free (of course—no changes there) and include unlimited collaborators.

Answer (score 6):

Once you have a paid account on GitHub, it is not obvious how to create a private repository. To create a private repository for an organization with paid account, go to https://github.com/organizations/MYORGANIZATIONNAME.

The only way I've figured how to navigate there is:

- Go to to your organization's home page: https://github.com/MYORGANIZATIONNAME
- Click on the "Edit MYORGANIZATION's Profile" button at the top right
- Click on the "GitHub" icon at the top left (non-obvious)
- Click on the "News Feed" tab (non-obvious)
- Click on the "New Repository" button at the right
  ...

Answer (score 5):

**Update (2019, latest)**

Since Jan 2019, GitHub allows private repositories for up to three collaborators.

**Previous answer:**

Here is the comparison for free plans listed by tree main Git Cloud based solutions:

[image]

Here is the comparison for paid plans listed by tree main Git Cloud based solutions:

[image]

#### Conclusion:

I'm not seeing people mentioning GitLab here, but it seems like the best free private plan for me. I myself am using it with no problems.

**GitHub:** If you have a student account or want to pay for $7 monthly, GitHub has the biggest community and you can take advantage of it's public repositories, forks, etc.

**Bitbucket:** If you use other products from Atlassian like [Jira](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jira_(software)) or [Confluence](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Confluence_%28software%29), Bitbucket works great with them.

**GitLab:** Everything that I care about (free private repository, number of private repositories, number of collaborators, etc.) are offered for free. This seems like the best choice for me.

Comment: The Github free info does not seem to be correct. VonC writes that there is unlimited free repositories on github, but with only three collaborators.
And I just made one of my repositories private, and have not yet used my creditcard.

Actually i consider making all my garbage work private, not to disturb searches finding unusefull things.