# Bitbucket private repository limits for free plan

Tags: git, github, bitbucket

I'm a university professor teaching a programming class. There will be a group assignment for this class and I'd like to monitor each group's progress, therefore I thought of using GitHub or Bitbucket to host the assignments. Each group will be composed of at most 4 students, and of course I will need to be able to see the repository as well.

Thus there will be a repository containing myself and students A, B, C and D, a second repository containing myself and students E, F, G and H, a third repository containing myself and students I, J, K and L, and so on.

Due to the particulars of this assignment, the repositories must necessarily be private.

I understand GitHub doesn't offer free private repositories, so I've crossed out that option. As for Bitbucket, am I correct in assuming that this doesn't exceed the limits for the free plan? If it does, are there other Git hosting services where I could host these assignments for free?

Comment: This is really a [cseducators.se] question.  You may want to check out that community.

Answer (score 2):

Bitbucket has an academic plan that should suit your needs. From https://bitbucket.org/product/pricing?tab=host-in-the-cloud :

> Do you offer free community or academic subscriptions?
>
> Yes! Community or academic subscriptions include unlimited private repositories for unlimited contributors which also includes 5 GB file storage for LFS and 500 build minutes for Pipelines to help you get started. You share build minutes and storage with all users on your team or personal account. Fees will apply for additional build minutes and file storage.
>
> How can I sign up for a free academic subscription?
>
> When you sign up with your academic email address, we will automatically convert your account to an unlimited academic plan. If your account doesn't automatically get converted, you can apply to have your institution added.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at GitHub education plan: https://education.github.com/

Also, GitLab is another alternative to GitHub and BitBucket. You can even host it on your network (for free)

Comment: GitHub has also (now) private repositories: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54080912/6309